# Programmatically add entry to user's crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I need to add a line to a user's crontab file.  Normally, I would do this with `crontab -e`, but I want to do it with a provisioning script.

Any clever methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
(crontab -u USERNAME -l ; echo "line to be added") | crontab -u USERNAME -
```

...or (although directly editing crontab files is not recommended):

```
echo "line to be added" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/USERNAME
```

(Assuming your provisioning script is running as root.)

Comment: you can also use the environment variable `$USER` for the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways

This will work if you want the user to edit it

```
echo "normal crontab line here" >> /var/spool/cron/user
```

If you don't want the user to edit it.. I'd drop a file into /etc/cron.d that is like

```
0 0 * * * username /path/to/file
```

You can call it whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this years later, if you find yourself in this sort of situation, you should take a very close look at configuration management tools.  In particular, Ansible is a great option that fits into existing infrastructure easily, and has [a nice cron module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cron_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could directly add new crons (if you have root privileges). 
you can also specify the run-as user.

> /etc/cron.d/filename

Comment: writing directly to the crontab file will not produce the expected results - the cron daemon needs to know about the changes

Comment: from what I know , this works ! Assuming the script written by the user validates the cron, this is the best way !

Comment: @symcbean, This actually depends on "cron" implementation in use. Traditional implementations needed to be somehow informed about the changes. Many modern implementations monitor the files and pick up any changes automatically.