# Programmatically adding two lines to crontab

Tags: amazon-ec2, bash, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to add two lines to the root crontab when building an AWS instance. I have a set of commands that are part of the "user data". These commands are run as root when creating the instance. I would like to add these two lines to the crontab:

```
@daily /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-daily.sh
@hourly /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-hourly.sh
```

I am using the following approach (based on an [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/296949/programmatically-add-entry-to-users-crontab) to this question):

```
(crontab -u ubuntu -l ; echo -e "@daily /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-daily.sh\n@hourly /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-hourly.sh") | crontab -u ubuntu -
```

However, this does not work when the instance is being created, but it does work if I log in and run this line. Is there any different way that I can append lines to the crontab?

Comment: Consider /etc/cron.d instead of /etc/crontab. /etc/cron.d is better when using system automation.

Comment: just wondering how you managed you aws secret keys with this? Specifically, how and where did you set the AWS_CONFIG_FILE variable so that cron is aware of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to mange crontabs programmatically, just create a file in `/etc/cron.d/` for example, `/etc/cron.d/example-cron`, and populate it with the aforementioned lines:

```
@daily ubuntu /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-daily.sh
@hourly ubuntu /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-hourly.sh
```

The only difference is that you have to include a user to run the cron as, as the second argument.  I set it to `ubuntu` in the example above, but you could set it to `root` for example.

Comment: The cron.d directories exist to solve issues like that. You can find a lot of *.d folders under /etc, and it makes life easier using them. I Agree with Kevin , this is best practice. And BTW crontabs they're (typically) stored uncer /var/spool/cron.

Comment: On that note, he could also place each script directly in /etc/cron.daily/, and /etc/cron.hourly/ respectively.  But I figured this way was the path of least resistance.

Comment: yeah but AFAIK those scripts they run as root only.

Comment: echo "@daily ubuntu /home/ubuntu/db-backup-to-s3-daily.sh" >> /etc/cron.d/example-cron  etc.  To get root you may need to do a sudo tee combination.